# CMake file for multiple subdirectories project

Tags: cmake

Note that I'm a noob at Cmake. This is my first attempt at it. I have a project that contains multiple subdirectories. You can see my project structure on the image below.

[image: Project structure]

My Cmake file contains this code:

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for CloudGamingPlatform, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("CloudGamingPlatform")

#subdirectories
include_directories(dependencies)
include_directories(dependencies/glm)
include_directories(dependencies/gli)
add_subdirectory(dependencies/glfw-3.3.2)

include_directories("$ENV{VULKAN_SDK}/include")
link_directories("$ENV{VULKAN_SDK}/lib") 
link_directories("$ENV{VULKAN_SDK}/etc/explicit_layer.d")

# Add source to this project's executable.

add_executable (CloudGamingPlatform "CloudGamingPlatform.cpp" "CloudGamingPlatform.h")

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "GLM included at ${GLM_INCLUDE_DIR}")

target_link_libraries(CloudGamingPlatform glfw ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(CloudGamingPlatform Vulkan::Vulkan)

target_link_directories(CloudGamingPlatform PUBLIC Engine)
target_link_directories(CloudGamingPlatform PUBLIC Utility)
target_link_directories(CloudGamingPlatform PUBLIC VulkanApplication)

# Set C++17
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

When I try to build my project, everything is good. But, when I try to run it, I get linker errors, like this one:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl VulkanApplication::createPhysicalDevices(void)" (?createPhysicalDevices@VulkanApplication@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl initVulkanApplication(void)" (?initVulkanApplication@@YAXXZ)  C:\Users\milos\Documents\Upwork\Projekti\CGP\vulkan\CloudGamingPlatform\out\build\x64-Debug\CloudGamingPlatform C:\Users\milos\Documents\Upwork\Projekti\CGP\vulkan\CloudGamingPlatform\out\build\x64-Debug\CloudGamingPlatform.cpp.obj 1
```

Is this error because of the cmake file, or am I missing something else? If yes, what is the right way to include all these subdirectories that I have?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do NOT use images for show the error messages. Instead, paste these error messages into the question post as **text**. Find how do your IDE may show the log: unlike to the separate messages on screenshot, this log would contain compiled files, files where error is raised, complete error message and so on. See [ask].

Comment: Your CMake doesn't appear to include anything about how the other components of your project are built (e.g. Engine, Utility, etc.). Are there other CMake files you are leaving out, or is this your *only* CMake file, and you want to include ALL of these sources and headers using it?

Comment: @squareskittles I want to include all of sources and headers in this one file. The project structure will change a lot, so I want to include these files with a few include commands. If that is possible at all.

Comment: Are the other components (e.g. Engine, Utility, etc.) intended to be libraries? Are they already built, or do you want CMake to orchestrate their compilation? It would seem, if these other components are not built, CMake would not know what they are and CMake will not complete successfully. Did you receive CMake errors? Can you please add details for how these different components, such as Vulkan and `gli`, depend on each other?

Comment: They shouldn't be libraries, but should be a part of the build. I didn't receive CMake errors, the compilation is ok. Vulkan and GLI are unrelated, but they should be included in other `.h` files